# How can I change the name of *.xml file in the eclipse IDE's project explorer with one of its element

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I m trying to write an eclipse plugin which is suppose to render xml file some different manner. What actually I want is to replace the name of the file displayed in the project explorer with one of its element without originally change the file name. for example I have a file named `1234.xml` with content

```
<name> dinesh </dinesh>
<college> NITT </college>
```

So I want to change the name of 1234.xml to dinesh.xml in the project explorer.

Can anybody tell me what are the possible ways I  can achieve this. 
I am new to eclipse plugin development.  So please provide me as much information as possible.

Comment: This is one way of doing. parse the contents of your xmlfile(1234.xml) and keep the value of name in a variable. Now form a new file and name the file with the variable.xml. Finally delete the 1234.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find the answer of what I wanted to do...

I have extended decorator extension point of eclipse to provide custom label provider for the desired files ...

One more thing to access the xml attribute use regex instead of xml parsing . It will make things bit faster than xml parsing ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way (I mean refactor) for this, so you must manually do it:

1. Change name of file `1234.xml` to `dinesh.xml`
2. Search in your project all references to `1234.xml` with `CTRL + H` / file search and appropiate patterns:
   [image]
3. Change all references found of `1234.xml` to `dinesh.xml`
4. If some issue appears search for `1234` in all the files to check if file was references only by name

Comment: I don't want to change the actual name of the file  in workspace. I just want a way to change the label of the file name with the name element of xml file. Basically I have a folder containing  few xml files with some system generated names ... each file has name attribute which is the name of the file ... I want to see that name attribute's value in my own viewer instead of the system generated name...